# Thematic map generation using openlayers

Tags: openlayers

I am working on a gis application which displays the crime locations on a map. One of my requirement is the generation of thematic maps depicting the crime rates in a locality. I searched the web and found a site that beatifully displays thematic map depending on zoom levels:
http://maps.met.police.uk/

I would like to know whether this type of thematic map generation is possible using openlayers. I am using PostGIS database with map generation using mapnik and tilecache and map display using Openlayers.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The maps.met.police.uk site seems to be using JQuery and Google Maps JS libraries.  I think the site makes an additional request to get vector data when the zoom changes the vector polygons to be more granular.

Here are some ways to consider doing this in OpenLayers:

1)  Set the minResolution and maxResolution (or minScale/maxScale) in two WMS OpenLayers.Layer layers (WMS or Vector) with both layers displayed, but only one of the two layers displayed at any specific zoom level.  You can scale this up to 3 or more layers depending on what you need.

2)  I saw a post about changing the visibility of the two layers based on the 'zoomEnd' event:  [Display WMS Layer Based on Zoom Level](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4000734/display-wms-layer-based-on-zoom-level)

3)  If you can represent your data as WFS then look at clustering:  http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/strategy-cluster-threshold.html

4)  If you're using something like ArcGIS on the back-end, then you could put multiple layers into the map document and use ArcMap to specify which layer shows at which zoom level for that ArcGIS service.  This is the approach I'd be taking on my project, FYI.

Answer (score 0):

http://indiemaps.com/blog/2012/04/introducing-openlayers-symbology/

This site might be of your interest.

Comment: Link only answers are discouraged. Please provide more detailed answer.